# How to execute vacuumdb on a non-default postgres installation

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

I have a postgres 12 cluster that is listening on port 5433 and the PGDATA directory is in a *non-default location* (`/u2/app/postgres/13/data`).

As part of the postgres upgrade (from version 12 to 13), I get the below error when I try to execute the `analyze_new_cluster.sh` script.

***vacuumdb: error: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?***

How do I tell the vacuumdb to connect/run on the correct cluster?

PS: Yes, I also have a default postgres cluster (port 5432) hosted on the same Linux server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) How exactly did you do the upgrade? **Add the complete command(s) as update to question** 2) What port is the 13 instance listening on?

Comment: vacuumdb is a client application and takes various settings for the connection. How did you start vacuumdb? (And why do you need it in the first place? I have never used it, no need for)

Comment: The postgres 12 cluster was upgraded to 13 using the pg_upgrade utility.

Comment: Upon successful cluster upgrade, the message to execute the "delete_old_cluster.sh" and "analyze_new_cluster.sh" scripts was displayed. The error message was generated when I had manually executed the "analyze_new_cluster.sh" script.

Comment: I repeat:  1) Add the complete command(s) as update to question 2) What port is the 13 instance listening on? Attention to detail is important in this sort of case.

Comment: Only you can see what's in analyze_new_cluster.sh, if you need help from others, you have to share the information. vacuumdb doesn't care about the PGDATA directory, it only needs a valid database connection and a database cluster that is active and accepts database connections. Please share the information, or close the question when no help is needed anymore

Comment: 1) What OS are you using? How did you install Postgres and from where? 2) I just did a test `pg_upgrade` from Postgres 14 to 15 and there was no `analyze_new_cluster.sh` created just a suggestion in the output to do `/usr/lib/postgresql/15/bin/vacuumdb --all --analyze-in-stages`. In that case and probably your case you will need to follow the answer from @AlejandroBurne. That  is run `/usr/pgsql-13/bin/vacuumdb ...` directly with the appropriate `port` number.

Answer (score 0):

You can add specific parameters connection (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-vacuumdb.html)

...vacuumdb also accepts the following command-line arguments for connection parameters:

-h host
--host=host
Specifies the host name of the machine on which the server is running. If the value begins with a slash, it is used as the directory for the Unix domain socket.

-p port
--port=port
Specifies the TCP port or local Unix domain socket file extension on which the server is listening for connections.

-U username
--username=username
User name to connect as.

-w
--no-password
Never issue a password prompt. If the server requires password authentication and a password is not available by other means such as a .pgpass file, the connection attempt will fail. This option can be useful in batch jobs and scripts where no user is present to enter a password.

-W
--password
Force vacuumdb to prompt for a password before connecting to a database.
This option is never essential, since vacuumdb will automatically prompt for a password if the server demands password authentication. However, vacuumdb will waste a connection attempt finding out that the server wants a password. In some cases it is worth typing -W to avoid the extra connection attempt.

--maintenance-db=dbname
Specifies the name of the database to connect to to discover which databases should be vacuumed, when -a/--all is used. If not specified, the postgres database will be used, or if that does not exist, template1 will be used. This can be a connection string. If so, connection string parameters will override any conflicting command line options. Also, connection string parameters other than the database name itself will be re-used when connecting to other databases...

Greetings, Alejandro

Comment: Sure! precisely he could add those connection parameters values ​​in the vacuumdb command line script to be able to establish the connection correctly

Comment: The contents of analyze_new_cluster.sh script are as follows.

Comment: cat analyze_new_cluster.sh
#!/bin/sh
"/usr/pgsql-13/bin/vacuumdb" --all --analyze-in-stages
echo
echo 'Done'

Comment: The upgrade steps are as follows.

Comment: export PG_DATA_OLD=/u2/postgres/data1
export PG_DATA_NEW=/u2/postgres/13/data
export PG_BIN_OLD=/usr/pgsql-12/bin
export PG_BIN_NEW=/usr/pgsql-13/bin

$PG_BIN_NEW/pg_upgrade \
--old-datadir $PG_DATA_OLD \
--new-datadir $PG_DATA_NEW \
--old-bindir $PG_BIN_OLD \
--new-bindir $PG_BIN_NEW –k

Comment: Add this information to your question **not** as comments.

Comment: It seems `pg_upgrade` has gone to a more generic approach for this stage and you would be best doing as @AlejandroBurne suggests and running `vacuumdb` directly with the correct `port`.